# Spring Java Config not loading assets

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, configuration

I'm trying to migrate from Spring XML configuration to Java Based, I make it run at least, but the assets (css,js,imgs) dont load and I'm getting an error 500 from response.
The asset folder is under webapp folder on the same level of WEB-INF
Anyone knows how can I fix It? Maybe a mistake on configuration.

**stacktrace:**

```
 07-May-2014 22:02:58.793 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.noCache(Cache.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:203)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResource(ApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResource(ApplicationContextFacade.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext.getResource(StandardContext.java:6510)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.exists(ServletContextResource.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.getResource(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2451)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And My Configuration Classes

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"br.com.cheetah.catalog.*"})
@Import({SecurityContext.class, PersistenceContext.class})
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringMvcContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/asset/**").addResourceLocations("../webapp/asset/**").setCachePeriod(20);
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver()
    {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

---

The Persistence Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"br.com.cheetah.catalog.repository"},
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
                       transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class PersistenceContext
{
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("PersistenceUnit");
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;

    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean()
                                                           .getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
    persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor()
    {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Initializer

```
@Order(1)
public class SpringInitializer extends
                               AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class<?>[]{SpringMvcContext.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

Security Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Resource
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/catalog/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage
                         ("/")
                .failureUrl("/?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl
                         ("/catalog/control-panel")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception
    {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/asset/**");
    }
}


@Order(2)
public class SecurityInitializer extends
                                 AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{
}
```

Comment: How about `addResourceLocations("/webapp/asset/")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andrei Stefan, I make it work simply replacing for

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/asset/**").addResourceLocations("/asset/**");
    }
```